# Why the body of onStartCommand() is getting executed only once?

Tags: android, service, android-service

To know the difference between IntentService and Service in Android, I created the below posted small test of a Service class. The MainActivity has a Button, when pressed, the 
service will be started using startService() as shown below in the code, which will result in a call to onStartCommand(). In onStartCommand(), i run a loop for 10 seconds, and I 
expected that, that loop will block the UI "the butoon". Actually that what happened exactly when I first time start the Service, but when I press the button after the 10 seconds
elapsed, it will result in a call to onStartCommand() but the log message inside the onStartCommand() never get displayed plus the UI is never blocked.

can anyone please explain what the body of the onStartCommand() is executed and blocks the UI only when the Service first started and never afterwards?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mbtnSend = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.mbtnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    this.mbtnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    });
}
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    registerReceiver(this.mBCR_VALUE_SENT, new IntentFilter(MyIntentService.INTENT_ACTION));

    this.mbtnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    this.mbtnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyIntentService.class);
            intent.putExtra("intent_key", ++i);
            startService(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**MyIntentService**:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private long mStartTime;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onCreate"));

    this.mStartTime = TimeUtils.getTSSec();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onStartCommand"));

    while ( (TimeUtils.getTSSec() - this.mStartTime) <=10) {
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("time: " + (TimeUtils.getTSSec() - this.mStartTime)));
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onBind"));

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onDestroy"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `mStartTime` to `TimeUtils.getTSSec()` in `onCreate()`, which means that it will get intialized only once.

Afterwards, `onStartCommand()` is called, but the `mStartTime` timestamp is not being updated, so the `while` loop never runs.

I believe that moving the line where you initialize `mStartTime` to `onStartCommand()` before the `while` loop will make your thread hang again.